Rouche's theorem without circular disks
How many (complex) roots does $f(z) = e^z+z$ have in $[-10,10] \times [-6\pi i, 6 \pi i]$?
I'm studying qualifier exam problems and this one showed up. At this level, I believe the the only expected/relevant tool is Rouche's theorem. Most problems of this kind given domains that are disks centered at the origin which is always super convenient when it comes to brute calculation of modulus. Here, we are given a rectangular domain; thus, the modulus of the complex points on the boundary of the domain vary as we travel along the boundary.
This post had a similar question about how to use Rouche in the absence of a circular domain and some commenters urged the use of the Argument Principle. But after reading some of the other answers, it seems there was some dispute about using the Argument Principle in such a context.

Did you mean to write $[-6\pi i,6\pi i]$ instead of $[-6\pi,6\pi i]$?

@JoséCarlosSantos yes, thank you. I fixed it

Have you tried approaching this using elementary means? After all, for any given $z$ you know what $\exp^{-1}(z)$ is. (I also have trouble seeing what you want to apply Rouché on, even if it turns out that you can.)
